# .mov File not playing in 64 bit google chrome - how to get a work around

Tags: google-chrome, quicktime

I have series of 360 photowarp virtual tours that have been made into an .mov files to show students the different types of room available to students.

You can see examples here:
http://housing.ucsc.edu/tours/cowell/index.html

In the new google chrome they are not showing up, not even an indicator that quicktime needs to be running.  I tired using HTML5  tag but that doesnt work.

Does anyone know of any work around to get the MOV file to work ? (I cannot upload to youtube since it is not a true video)

Thanks !
Becca

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no workaround; in versions of Chrome that do not support QuickTime ([which fairly soon will be all of them](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/11/the-final-countdown-for-npapi.html)) you cannot play .mov files, since those are QuickTime files.

You'll either need to use a different technology for the tours, based on web standards, or have people download the .mov files to view outside the browser.

Comment: Smorgan, is there a way to make an statement show up for those google chrome users to go into a different browser while trying to fix this?

Comment: You can use navigator.plugins to check if a user has the QuickTime plugin available or not.